# join 2 tables with update, but only rows with matching value

Tags: sqlite, join, sql-update

I am having two tables which i wish to join.
I am not using foreign keys.

table structure table1
id,val1

table structure table2
id,val2

I am using now following command:

```
update table1 set val1=(SELECT val2 FROM table2 WHERE table1.id LIKE table2.id)
```

How can i force sqlite not to insert a value in table1 if an id does not exist in table2?

Comment: Why `LIKE`? Using `=`, if possible, would be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

To use exact comparisons, use `=` instead of `LIKE`.

To update only those rows where a match is found, use a WHERE clause:

```
UPDATE Table1
SET val1 = (SELECT val2
            FROM Table2
            WHERE Table1.id = Table2.id)
WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM Table2);
```

If you omit the WHERE clause, rows without a match get updated with a NULL value.

Comment: Unfortunately, my sqlite3 still populates val1 with values from closest match with this solution

Comment: it takes a value of an another id, val1 becomes val2 of table1.id!=table2.id, i prefere that it will set NULL if there is no table1.id  in table2